# background-size:cover performance issues

Tags: performance, css, safari, webkit

I'm having performance issues (especially in Safari) with using a large number of elements with `background-size: cover`. I've added `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` which did help a little, but not as much as I'd like. I'm really looking for a pure css fix if possible.

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem? The rending time?

Comment: Most likely the issue is the the actually size of the image, try optimizing or compressing it.

Comment: What would the reason for using a large number of elements be?

Comment: Thanks all, it's a layout based on many floating flexible elements with full-sized background images, so using background-size: cover is pretty much a must. The images have been aggressively compressed, but Safari seems to be having painting issues. Mostly when scrolling you see a lag on part of the image while repaint is happening.

Comment: So if you don't use background-size:cover, what happens?  Performance is fine? I just saw a video on optimizing images for Safari at the [WWDC 2012 conference](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) called "Optimizing Web Content...".  If you register as an Apple web developer (if not already), it's free and could help.  One thing it said is that it's the size (width x height) not the compression (bytes) that matter with performance.  The bytes only matter for downloading, Safari than uncompresses the image and saves that in memory.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this from a "repaint" approach. However, it does seem that there is an issue with the first rendering when there are many elements. This link will lag and take a long time to even load: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfkvu/embedded/result/) . However, it semi reproduces the effect noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/VqUTf/embedded/result/)***

`background-size:cover` has terrible performance across the board. I have found many issues with using it before, and have abandoned it in favor of this approach.

Use an image inside of the div, size the div to the dimensions you wish to use. Have the image sized as such:

```
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

And directly assign the url of the image being loaded to `src="url"`.

You can see even with this strenuous test that it does just fine (even when tested in safari - jQuery used for brevity in demo)

```
var place = "http://placehold.it/";
var all = $("<div>");
for( var w = 5; w < 100; w++ ){
 for( var h = 5; h < 100; h++ ){
  var nwln = $('<div>');
  var img = $('<img class="sq">');
  nwln.width(w*2);
  nwln.height(h*2);
  var url = place + w + "x" + h;
  img[0].src = url;
  nwln.append(img);
  all.append(nwln);
 }
}
$("#grid").append(all);
```

Comment: @BoltClock - Is there an improvement I can make here?

Comment: I think he was just referencing how it's kinda sad that there is performance issues around `background-size: cover`. Just a note, I used this method with `position: fixed` instead of `relative` and it's working much better. Thanks!