# Efficient way to use full page background image with css animations

Tags: css, css-animations, translate3d

I'm having a problem with full page background image and css animations. No matter how I try to optimize the animation it always runs slow (way above 60fps threshold) on top of the background image. I use css `translate3d` property to move object around. If I remove the background image everything runs very smoothly and fast.

Comment: "way above 60fps" is fast. What is your bg image like? Is it pattern, dose it use `background-size:cover;`? Make a jsfiddle...

Comment: Yes, it's `background-size:cover;` and when I disable that property everything runs much faster but then the background becomes useless...

Comment: You would probably have a lot easier time using a non-background image and using JS to position it, or use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502454/background-sizecover-performance-issues

Comment: Yeah, if you use JS to position it will speed it up. Add translate3d to the background as well, just to GPU accelrate it. Check out my portolfio - mirohristov.com - it uses bg cover and has heavy animation sprites on top but still works fast. I remember running into similar problems though.

Comment: @miro Yeah, but you're not using `background-size: cover` and you're benefiting immensely by using [Matthew Wagerfield's parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) to handle animation on those layers, which uses `requestAnimationFrame`, ample selector caching, has a very efficient position calculation routine, and avoids expensive DOM operations (unlike most of what you have in `main.js`). As for `translate3d` and GPU acceleration, it's a bit more complicated than what you're indicating: http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/

Comment: `background-size:100%` is the same as `cover`. Agreed with everything else you said. Good to know.